# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ./oozie-setup.sh sharelib create -fs hdfs://localhost:9000

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, oozie

I built Oozie and was creating share lib in hdfs but it is giving the following error.
I followed all the steps but this is the only one that went wrong.

```
 setting CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx1024m"
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/IOFileFilter
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2866)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1676)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 6 more
```

thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

copy hadoop libs in extlib directory and prepare war then try it.

`cp  $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/*/hadoop-*.jar./libext/`

`cp  $HADOOP_HOME /share/hadoop/*/lib/*.jar./libext/`

`cp  mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jarlibext/`

`bin/oozie-setup.sh prepare-war`

run this after copy and prepare.

`./bin/oozie-setup.sh sharelib create -fs hdfs://IP(HOSTNAME):9000`